# Use of ^ and gsub in Lua

Tags: string, lua, gsub, lua-patterns

```
function title case(theString)  
    return (theString:gsub("^%a", string.upper):gsub("%s+%a", string.upper)) 
end
```

1. I have the above mentioned code. I wanted to know the use of `^` operator in the above code. I know that `^` is used in sets to exclude/negate the succeeding values in a set but since it's not a set, what is `^` meant for ?
2. Why is `gsub` used twice in above code? Both the times, the letters are being converted to upper case! Please explain what's exactly happening in above line of code.

Comment: `return ((' '..theString):gsub("%s%a", string.upper):sub(2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `^` in the beginning of a pattern is the anchor for "the beginning of the string", i.e, `"^%a"` matches a `"%a"`(a letter) only if it's in the beginning of the string.
2. The first `string.gsub()` is to make the first letter in the string uppercase, the second `string.gsub()` is to make the first letter of the other words (a letter that is follows a whitespace) uppercase.

   For instance, a string `"hello world"` turns into `"Hello world"` after the first `string.gsub()`, then turns into `"Hello World"` after the second `string.gsub()`.